# How can I remove password set up earlier in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I once set up the password to access Jupyter Notebook. But now I want to remove it. How can I do that?

[image]

It is like this, and I want to remove it from Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove password for Jupyter Notebooks and set token again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230706/how-to-remove-password-for-jupyter-notebooks-and-set-token-again)

Answer (score -1):

You can restart your jupyter server again using commands like below:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.password='sha1:90aa25f6c644:94841fd38b17d02c7c9940896330015ad03850a2'
```

And the password was generated by the following:

```
from notebook.auth import passwd; passwd('helloworld')
```

And then you can login with password: helloworld

Comment: Is this the way I can remove password completely? Or this objective for this is just to change it?

Comment: You chan change the password to your own, just using the python statements at the below in the answer. And if you want to remove the password, just launch "jupyter notebook", you will be prompted to enter the token display in console.