# How to reset the 'jupyter notebook password' to default set token again?

Tags: linux, server, jupyter-notebook

I mistakenly typed 'jupyter notebook password' command in my virtual enviromint that I created to run anaconda (linux). This prompted me to set a password. I just gave 'a blank' password to the following:

Enter password:  *

Verify password: *

The problem is when I call 'jupyter notebook', it does not provide me with the full address with its token anymore. I only get  http://localhost:8888/ instead without the token and I cannot open Jupiter notebook from my virtual env).

My question is, how I can reset it back to the default where it used to give me the full address with the token?
another words, how do I make it like the way it was or how do I get the token back?

Below is link for the reference document, look at the 'Automatic Password setup' section with command I used --> $ jupyter notebook password
https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html

Comment: Have look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230706/how-to-remove-password-for-jupyter-notebooks-and-set-token-again).

Comment: Yes, I did. However, though the request is similar, the problem is slightly different. He did some more steps that I have. I don't want to create another problem by implementing another solution. But if an SME tells me the solution is applicable, I will use it. Do you know?